# How can I read text ( text language is not fixed ) from a file and perform some operation write those in another file?

Tags: java

I have a text file written in Bangla, English, Hindi, etc. I want to read this file. Then I want to perform some operation on this string . Then, finally, I will write the resulting string into another file.

I tried this but it didn't solve my problem. So, what should I do to solve my problem?

```
BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(
        new FileInputStream  ("Input1.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8) );
Writer writeFirst = new BufferedWriter(
    new OutputStreamWriter(
        new FileOutputStream("Input.txt",true), StandardCharsets.UTF_16));
String str =null ;
while ((str = read.readLine()) != null) {
     String[] words = str.split(" ");
     // will do some operation on those strings
     for(String u : words) {
         writeFirst.write(u + "     ") ;
      }
      writeFirst.write("\n") ;
}
```

Input:

```
i love my country
আমি আমার দেশকে ভালোবাসি
```

Output I get:

```
��I       l o v e       m y       c o u n t r y      
��I       l o v e       m y       c o u n t r y      
��I       l o v e       m y       c o u n t r y      
��I       l o v e       m y       c o u n t r y      
��I       l o v e       m y       c o u n t r y      
��I       l o v e       m y       c o u n t r y      
��I       l o v e       m y       c o u n t r y      
��I      l o v e      m y      c o u n t r y     
��i      l o v e      m y      c o u n t r y     
��i   l o v e   m y   c o u n t r y ��i   l o v e   m y   c o u n t r y ��i   l o v e   m y   c o u n t r y ��i   l o v e   m y   c o u n t r y   � �   �     � �   �   �     � �   �   �   �     � �   �   �   �   �   �   �
```

Comment: What does not work? What result do you expectß What result do you get? Why is it wrong?

Comment: My output file shows " 뿯붿뿯ঽ뿯ঽ뿯ঽ뿯ঽ뿯ঽ뿯ঽ뿯ঽ뿯ঽ뿯ঽ_NEL뿯ঽ뿯ঽ뿯ঽ뿯ঽ뿯ঽ뿯ঽ_NN뿯ঽ뿯ঽ뿯ঽ뿯ঽ뿯ঽ뿯ঽ뿯ঽ뿯ঽ_ADJ
뿯ঽ뿯ঽ뿯ঽ뿯ঽ뿯ঽ뿯ঽ뿯ঽ뿯ঽ뿯ঽ뿯ঽ_NN
뿯ঽ뿯ঽ뿯ঽ뿯ঽ뿯ঽ_NEA
뿯ঽ뿯ঽ뿯ঽ뿯ঽ뿯ঽ뿯ঽ뿯ঽ뿯ঽ뿯ঽ뿯ঽ_NN
뿯ঽ뿯ঽ뿯ঽ뿯ঽ뿯ঽ_NN
뿯ঽ뿯ঽ뿯ঽ" . But my main fil( which i read ) is written in Bengali and English . How can i write into my output file as an exact language ?

Comment: Is the input file encoded using UTF-8 as you assume? Could you please [edit] your question and include a *small* sample of the input file?

Comment: Are you actually viewing your output file with an application that supports (and uses) UTF-16?

Comment: You need to consume the input file before you open it again for output. Otherwise on some platforms you will empty it, while on others you will get an access violation.

Comment: Dear , EJP , when i did that by using C# , i got "access denied " . But in java , till now i couldn't get that. Is there any way to solve that issue in C# ? I gave that folder " everyone control " , but my effort is in vain .Could you please help me for my C# solution ?

Comment: Dear @LutzHorn , i have updated my question . Cuuld you please take a look ?

Comment: Is it importatnt that the output file uses the UTF-16 encoding? Wouldn't UTF-8 be OK?

Answer (score 1):

Your code basically works. If you have to use UTF-16, I recommend to change the encoding of the output file from **UTF-16** to **UTF-16BE** explicitly.

I've improved the resource usage a little bit:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(Paths.get(args[0]).toFile());
            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(Paths.get(args[1]).toFile(), true);
            Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(os, StandardCharsets.UTF_16BE);
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(writer)) {
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] words = line.split(" ");
            System.out.println(
                    String.format("writing line '%s' which has %d words",
                            line, words.length));
            // will do some operation on those strings
            for (String word : words) {
                out.write(word + "     ");
            }
            out.write("\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The resulting file (give on `args[1]`) is correctly encoded. This can be validated using [`iconv`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/iconv) by converting it to UTF-8:

```
$ iconv -f UTF16BE -t UTF8 output.UTF16BE.txt
i     love     my     country     
আমি     আমার     দেশকে     ভালোবাসি
```

As you can see, the content is correct and includes the added whitespace between the words.

Comment: Thank you very mych . But another thing is , i want to show output files as i     love     my     country     
আমি     আমার     দেশকে     ভালোবাসি ,not in encoded mode . Could you please help me ?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you want to do. What do you mean by "show"? Any editor that can read UTF-16BE encoded text should be able to display the output file. Where and how do you want to display the output?

Comment: I want     "i     love     my     country     
আমি     আমার     দেশকে     ভালোবাসি  "rather than " 믯䦿††氠癯⁥††祭††挠畯瑮祲††ਠꛠ꺦ꛠ₿††ꛠ꺦ꛠ낦††ꚦ꟠뚦ꛠ螧††궦ꛠ늦꟠겦ꛠ뢦ꛠ₿††"

Comment: The output you want is exactly what I get. As I said, it may be hard to directly read the UTF-16BE encoded file. But as it *does* contain the text you want which I've demonstrated using `iconv` above. Does the output have to be encoded using UTF-16BE? Or would UTF-8 be OK?

Comment: Then change the encoding of the `OutputStreamWriter` to `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` and you should get a nice UTF-8 encoded file that can be read.

Comment: Sorry,nothing looks good . here is the current output "믯䦿††氠癯⁥††祭††挠畯瑮祲††ਠꛠ꺦ꛠ₿††ꛠ꺦ꛠ낦††ꚦ꟠뚦ꛠ螧††궦ꛠ늦꟠겦ꛠ뢦ꛠ₿††뾻⁉††潬敶††洠⁹††潣湵牴⁹††蚦ꛠ뾦††蚦ꛠ뺦ꛠ₰††ꛠ螧ꛠ閦꟠₇††ꛠ뺦ꛠ讧ꛠ뺦ꛠ뾦††ਠ"